# Projection alignment

Tags: coordinate-system, rotate, ellipsoid, geodesic, move

I am trying to align my coordinates with known geodesic markers in QGIS 3.34.1 but all my measured points are out with a bearing of about 35 degrees and 2.6m away. My distances are correct when measuring.

Given that I have 3 geodesic markers, and accurate 3 GPS markers (mine), how easy/difficult would it be to align the GRS80 ellipsoid for a custom projection?

I need my coordinates in the Greek Grid to align with the geodesic markers, is there a better way to do this?

I have the geodesic markers and the ultimate solution would be to create a custom projection that would align the GPS with Greek grid by moving, rotating the ellipsoid thus correcting local projection errors.

My problem is I am at the limits of the Greek grid projection and it is inaccurate. Call it dumb and I know, I have accurate location data that need to align with an inaccurate system!

Comment: I don't know the terminology in QGIS but have you tried to georeference the data? Or another term might be spatial adjustment. Both methods use control points (points that exist in both coordinate systems) to try to mathematically align the 'source' data to the target.